# Why does merging two bar chart subplots into one change the axis and how can I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have two dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,3),index=[2,3,4,5],columns=["I","J","K"])
df2=pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.rand(4,3),index=[1,2,3,4],columns=["I","J","K"])
```

After creating a bar chart I get:

[image: subplots]

Now I want to merge them into one figure so I tried:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True)
ax1 = df1.plot.bar(legend=True, rot=0, stacked=True, width=0.1, position=1, colormap="bwr", ax=ax, alpha=0.7)
ax2 = df2.plot.bar(legend=True, rot=0, stacked=True, width=0.1, position=0, colormap="BrBG", ax=ax, alpha=0.7)
plt.show()
```

But the result isn't what I would expect:
[image: After_joining]

As you can see, I would want the x-axis to have values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and the graphs to correspond to their original index value. Where is the problem and how could I fix it?

Also if it was possible I would need to set the new axis values automatically since I have many of these dataframes all with different axis values and inserting the new axis values manually would take a long time. Maybe I could use `.unique()` in the index column and implement this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reindex both dataframes to the same index:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(10 * np.random.rand(4, 3), index=[2, 3, 4, 5], columns=["I", "J", "K"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(10 * np.random.rand(4, 3), index=[1, 2, 3, 4], columns=["I", "J", "K"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
combined_index = df1.index.union(df2.index)
df1.reindex(combined_index).plot.bar(legend=True, rot=0, stacked=True, width=0.1, position=1,
                                     colormap="bwr", alpha=0.7, ax=ax)
df2.reindex(combined_index).plot.bar(legend=True, rot=0, stacked=True, width=0.1, position=0,
                                     colormap="BrBG", alpha=0.7, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas stacked bars for two dataframes with combined indices]

Pandas bar plot creates categorical x-ticks (internally numbered `0,1,2,...`) using the dataframe's index. First the internal tick positions are assigned, and then the labels. By using the same index for both dataframes, the positions will coincide.

Comment: Indeed.  The update just seems a bit more following pandas philosophy. I only tested with these numerical indices. `index.union()` might be safer, e.g. with dates.

Comment: The first answer `combined_index = np.unique(df1.index.to_list() + df2.index.to_list())` works perfectly too. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.